# Emulate cortex-a53 (arm64) in qemu

Tags: qemu, arm64, emulation

I would like to emulate with qemu an aarch64 system. The system has been tested on the board and works perfectly. The board is based on the allwinner A64. I started using qemu from this repo : git://git.qemu.org/qemu.git but the command I run just doesn't start it, I get a black screen :

```
./qemu-system-aarch64 \
  -machine type=virt \
  -cpu cortex-a53 \
  -nographic \
  -smp 1 \
  -m 2048 \
  -kernel my_image
  -serial stdio
```

I'm not sure about the need of pointing to the kernel file and initrd one and there's no -v flag for qemu to debug

Comment: Did you ever get a satisfactory answer?

Comment: @DaniëlW.Crompton Unfortunately not

Answer (score 0):

- First you have to make sure that you have compiled your kernel file according to aarch64. You can check this by running the "file my_image" command in the terminal.
- Second, make sure that the qemu repo for "qemu-system-aarch64" is working properly. You can find a simple qemu example and run it.
- Thirdly, you should check if the qemu version you selected has cortex-a53 in the cpu list. You can see this simply with the command "qemu-system-aarch64 -M ?"

Answer (score -2):

You can use gdb for debug kernel. Just start qemu as gdb server:  need add another two options in the end: " -S -s" when you run qemu. After you could use gdb client from aarch64 cross tools for debugging your kernel. Also looks like '-dtb' options is also required.

Answer (score -3):

I will say I've never used qemu, but I see that you're using nographic and not setting up a console.   You can open a console connection to qemu, which will let you halt the emulated arm processor, and observe the registers and processor state.  Try checking out this link, and search for "QEMU WITHOUT X":

https://www.aurel32.net/info/debian_arm_qemu.php

Edit: Full documenation of console commands is here:
http://wiki.qemu.org/download/qemu-doc.html#pcsys_005fmonitor